# How can I map these five keyboard actions to a single key in Vim?

Tags: linux, vim

I want to map a key so that it will do the following actions in Vim. Suppose I am editing a file; I want it set up so that if I press <kbd>F2</kbd>, I will accomplish the same thing I would if I did the following:

1. press <kbd>ESC</kbd>
2. type colon (`:`)
3. type `w`
4. press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. press <kbd>ESC</kbd> again
6. type `i` to go back to insert mode

Is this possible?

Comment: I’m not really sure why anybody would be voting this one down. I agree with some of them that the described way of doing things is not really how Vim is meant to be used, but the answers it’s getting here are really helpful for someone trying to learn more about Vim key mappings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literal answer: Yes. You can use this:

```
:inoremap <F2> <Esc>:w<CR>I
```

but it won’t do exactly what you want (the cursor will be at the wrong place).

Anton beat me to the less literal (but correct) answer.

The best answer, though, is this: **Don't use Vim incorrectly.** You should never spend so much time in insert mode that you need a shortcut to get out of it, save the file, and then get back in. With all other editors, you’re in “insert mode” all the time, and only temporarily pop into a menu or dialog or whatever; in Vim, you should learn to reverse this. Only pop into insert mode to edit or add something; never use arrow keys to move the cursor while in insert mode; spend the majority of your time in command (normal) mode, and after a bit of adjustment to the new paradigm, you will find that your editing speed has increased.

Comment: For a quick save, I'd make an exception for insert-mode mappings, but in general, you're right.

Comment: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Comment: @user1953864: You can put the line `inoremap <F2> <C-O>:w<CR>` into `~/.vimrc` file (colon not needed).

Comment: @user1953864 you would put this in any file that's loaded by Vim at runtime. Preferably in your .vimrc file. :)

Comment: @Amadan thanks buddy that worked. why did u put  `inoremap` instead of `noremap`. Also that will really ease my job. Are there any more short cuts like these which people are using so that i can start applying those in vim , rather than learning one of those in every month or so

Comment: @user1953864: `inoremap` will only do it in insert mode; given that `<C-O>` only has that meaning in insert mode as well, it is fitting. I can't tell you about "any more shortcuts like these which people are using" because people *aren't* using them, except the beginners that want to make `vim` into Notepad instead of learning to use it efficiently in its own right.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's possible, but it doesn't do what you want if the cursor is at the end of line.

To get file saved on <kbd>F2</kbd> in *insert* mode, use the following mapping:

```
:imap <F2> <C-O>:w<CR>
```

Comment: Given that he said `I` (as in, capital `i`), it won't do what he wants even when the cursor isn't at the end of the line :p

Answer (score 3):

Writing the mapping is almost easier than your description.

First, you need to determine from which *mode* the mapping will be used, because that determines what `:map` variant you will use. You’ll probably want to use this in *insert mode*, so you’ll use `:inoremap`.

The format of the mapping is:

```
:..noremap {keys} {rhs}
```

You want `<F2>` (see `:help key-notation`) for `keys`. For `{rhs}`, just concatenate the keys listed in your description.

To persist the mapping, add it to `~/.vimrc`. (See `:help vimrc`.)

P.S. The [alternative given by Anton Kovalenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14270483/758011) is probably better for what you’re trying to do, but here I’ve given you the general recipe for future key mappings.